# Does there exist an entire function $f$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{n}{2n-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I know that I am supposed to somehow apply the Identity Theorem, but other than that I am absolutely clueless.

Any hints?

Comment: Consider $f(x)(2-x)$

Comment: Similar to [Does there exist $f:B(0,1) \to \Bbb{C}$, holomorphic such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{3-2n}$ for all $n >2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493238)

Answer (score 1):

Letting $n\to\infty$ gives
$$f(0)=\frac12.$$
Also
$$f(1/n)=\frac1{2-1/n}.$$
By the identity theorem, applied at $z=0$,
$$f(z)=\frac1{2-z}$$
in a neighbourhood of zero. But this will continue to a function
with a pole at $z=2$.

Answer (score 0):

With $x=\frac{1}{n}$ we get $$f(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{2}{x}-1}=\frac{1}{2-x}$$

Comment: which is not entire